# swift - cellForRowAt never called

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with creating a table view in UITableViewController. The number of rows returns non-zero number and height is set in storyboard. But the `cellForRowAt`is never called.

Here is the code:

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleCell

    cell.title.text = "THIS IS A TESTE"
    cell.desc.text = "THIS IS A TESTE"

    return cell
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: did you connected delegate and datasource to your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your viewDidload make

```
yourtableView.delegate = self
yourtableView.dataSource = self
```

Don't forget to pull a reference outlet of your tableView.
[image]

Comment: I put this code `self.tableView.register(ArticleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "articleCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self `  but now its give me the follow error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: NO, just add these line in your ViewDidLoad.
at first pull a reference outlet of your tableview.

Comment: wow, its working like a charm now. The reference was there, but I dont know what happened.  Thank you mister.